# How to add this figure in 2 column file?

Tags: floats

I want to add like the figure below each subfigure has (a) (b) c d. Then a main title for it. My code is this but its wrong. My image is at the bottom.

```
\begin{figure*}[htb]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{a}
\caption{(a)}\label{label-a}
\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[b]{.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{b}
\caption{(b)}\label{label-b}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Load the `subcaption` package, and the `subfigure` environment.

Comment: Which document class do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update the beow coding with the packages `subfloat`, `subfig`, `graphicx`

Add sub caption if needed in the option `\subfloat[caption here]`

```
\begin{figure*}[htb]
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure(a)}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure(b)}}\\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure(c)}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure(d)}}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Did you try out this code? I would use `\columnwidth` rather than `\textwidth`, and I'd use spacers between the first/second and third/fourth subfigures.